# Блокировка сетевых портов

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу написать програмулину чтобы блокировала все сетевые порты:) этак вирус для начальника.Пусть сидит на одном ftp и без танчиков. Подскажите пожалуйста какие классы использовать и тд...

Comment: программа для его компьютера или сервера? Почему бы просто не настроить стандартный фаервол или отредактировать svhost направив ip в нули

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string parameters = "advfirewall firewall add rule " +
                              "name=\"{0}\" " +
                              "dir={1} " +
                              "action={2} " +
                              "protocol={3} " +
                              "localport={4}";

        string rulename = "Custom TCP rule";
        string direction = "in"; // in,out
        string action = "block"; // allow,block,bypass
        string protocol = "TCP"; // TCP, UDP
        int localport = 2300;

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe");
        info.Arguments = String.Format(parameters, rulename, direction, action, protocol, localport);
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        var process = Process.Start(info);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Или так

http://notessysadmin.com/how-close-or-open-ports-in-windows-firewall

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=1-79 name="Block_TCP-1"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=81-442 name="Block_TCP-2"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=444-3388 name="Block_TCP-3"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=3390-65535 name="Block_TCP-4"

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80 name="HTTP"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP  localport=443 name="HTTPS"

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.0.0/24 name="RDP-1"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3389 remoteip=x.x.x.x name="RDP-2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Запущенную программу всегда можно отключить и/или зайти под другим пользователем/ОС и она уже не будет запущена. Проще покопаться в настройках маршрутизатора, если такой имеется, там всё по своему вкусу и возможностям прошивки настроить. Ещё простой вариант: исправить файл hosts, если есть доступ к его машине, но это тоже легко найти и очистить обратно.